# on checking the child checkbox parent does not checked vise versa Works perfectly

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Hi I've these check boxes in `asp.net repeater` when I click the parent check box as you can see in this [picture](http://prntscr.com/9go1tb)  all child check boxes get check, in the other hand when I check the child check box the parent did not get selected. I'm using `Jquery` to achieve this 
My current `ASP.NET` code is as given below

```
<ul id='<%# "p_"+Eval("ApplicationId") %>' class="child-ul-hide child-ul">
                                                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptrPages" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrPages_ItemDataBound">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <li>
                                                         <%-- <span id='<%# "sp_"+Eval("PageId") %>' class="parent arrow-right" state="hide"></span>--%>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblSpaces" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Spaces") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                <asp:Literal ID="ltrArrowSpan" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PageTitle") %>'
                                                                        CssClass='<%# "page Pid_"+ Eval("ParentId")%>' PageId='<%# Eval("PageId") %>' ParentId='<%# Eval("ParentId") %>'
                                                                        Checked='<%# Eval("IsEnable")== null ? false: Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsEnable").ToString())  %>' />
                                                                </label>
                                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdPageId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("PageId") %>' />
```

and my `JavaScript` code is as following 
as you can see I'd tried a couple of other stuff and used Intermediate snippiest too but when they are invited to `ASP.NET` Nothing goes as planed. many of you might suggest to use `<input type='checkbox'/>` sorry I can't do that

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        /* Hide Show Tree lis
         *******************************************/
        $(".parent").click(function () {

            var ID = $(this).attr("id");
            var state = $("#" + ID).attr("state");
            if (state == "hide") {

                $("#" + ID).attr('state', 'show');
                $("#" + ID).addClass("arrow-down").removeClass("arrow-right");
                ID = ID.replace("s", "");
                $("#" + ID).addClass("child-ul-show").removeClass("child-ul-hide");
            }
            else {

                $("#" + ID).attr('state', 'hide');
                $("#" + ID).addClass("arrow-right").removeClass("arrow-down");
                ID = ID.replace("s", "");
                $("#" + ID).addClass("child-ul-hide").removeClass("child-ul-show");
            }
        });

    //    /* START Parent Enable CheckBox Click Event
    //   *********************************************/
        $(".page input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {

            var PageId = $(this).parent('.page').attr("PageId");

            var parentId = $(this).parent('.page').attr("ParentId");

            var EnableStatus = $(this).prop("checked");

            // Check/ Uncheck Controls Checkboxes
            $("." + PageId + " input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', EnableStatus);

            //Check unCheck Childs Checkboxes
            $(".Pid_" + PageId + " input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', EnableStatus);


            $(".Pid_" + PageId + " input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                PageId = $(this).parent('.page').attr("PageId");
                EnableStatus = $(this).prop("checked");
                $(".Pid_" + PageId + " input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', EnableStatus);
            });

            //$(".page input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
            //$(".Pid_" + ParentId + " input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
            //    debugger;
            //    EnableStatus = $(this).prop("checked");
            //    if (EnableStatus) {
            //        $(".page input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', EnableStatus);
            //        return false;
            //    }
            //});
            debugger;
            parentId = parseInt(parentId);
            if (parentId>0) {
                $("input[type='checkbox'][ParentId^='" + parentId + "']").prop('checked', true);

            }


            /*/ */
            //$('input[name=' + parentId + '][value=Done][type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').attr({
            //    checked: 'checked',
            //    disabled: 'disabled'
            //});



        });
```

Comment: A good thing to do is take your html *output* as generated by the asp.net page, and together with the javascript embed it in your question as a runnable javascript/html snippet. This will separate your particular problem from the rest of your application... and more importantly, will make it *much* easier for other people to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see is that you've a single check box that at a time is acting as a parent as well as a child, I don't have any idea what made you to do that.
Lets get to the answer.
Add an attribute to the class as 
`ParentId='<%# Eval("ParentId")`
get that attribute

```
                var ParentId = $(this).parent('.page').attr("ParentId");
```

use the JavaScript `parseInt` to parse your id as integer  than do this one

```
   ParentId= parseInt(ParentId);
            if (ParentId > 0) {

                $(".p_" + ParentId + " input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
                $(".Pid_" + ParentId + " input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {

                    EnableStatus = $(this).prop("checked");
                    if (EnableStatus)
                    {
                        $(".p_" + ParentId + " input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', EnableStatus);
                    }

                });
            }
```

Hope this will help you